# WPF WebView in dialogue window shows no content first time displayed

Tags: wpf, xaml, webview

I have a WPF application running on a Win10 desktop using the new (Microsoft.Toolkit.Wpf.UI.Controls.WebView v5.0.0.0) `WebView` control in a dialog window. The first time this dialog window is created, `WebView` navigation successfully completes but most of the time the `WebView` stubbornly continues to display a blank page.

If I minimise that first instance of the dialogue window and restore it, the content is instantly rendered. If I close that window instance and create a new one, the control generally renders as expected.

Changing the `WebView.Visibility` in code to `Collapsed` and then back to `Visible` on navigation completion doesn't fix the blank page.

Has anyone seen this behaviour? Does anyone have a solution to provoke `WebView` to actually render?

In theory the new `WebView` is a better architectural option than reverting to the old `WebBrowser` so I'm loathe to go down that path.

---

Additional detail

- Windows 10 desktop, x64, targeting .NET 4.6.2, WPF 4.x.
  The `WebView` instance is defined in XAML (without a `Source` binding) inside a `UserControl`.
- The `UserControl` is embedded in a window defined in XAML, which only contains a root level `Grid` to contain the `UserControl`.
- That window is shown via `ShowDialog()`.
- Source navigation is performed in code behind controlled by the current selection of a `TabControl`.
- The `WebView` is NOT defined in the `TabControl` item template (doing so throws exceptions most of the time on tab selection change). It is in a container that is a sibling to the `TabControl`.
- The `NavigationCompleted` event reports success.

Answer (score 0):

I found that attempting to minimise and then restore the containing window in code didn't fix it, despite minimise & restore working when the user does it. Invalidating the control layout or visual or arrange didn't work. Maximising and restoring the window in code did, but is visually annoying, but it led me to two reasonable workarounds:

---

Configure the `WebView.Visibility` to be `Collapsed` in XAML and either:

- handle the `UserControl.Loaded` event and set the visibility to `Visible`; or
- handle the `WebView.NavigationStarting` event and set it to `Visible`.

Those are easiest if starting out collapsed won't cause unacceptable visual disruption. Getting in early via the `Loaded` event helps. Starting out `Hidden` doesn't work.

---

Leave `WebView.Visibility` configured to `Visible` in XAML, handle the `WebView.NavigationStarted` event in the `UserControl`, and then if it's the first time the handler called in this process do something like this to cause the control to resize and then restore the original size:

```
var height = Height;
Height = 0;
Application.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(
    (Action)(() => { Height = height; }), 
    DispatcherPriority.Input
);
```

Dispatching the value restoration seems to be required (although maybe calling something like `InvalidateLayout()` in between would suffice).